# Need to find bitcoin wallet circa 2015

Tags: wallet-recovery, passphrase

During this bitcoin boom I remember going to a bitcoin event and the host had me open a wallet and used an ATM to deposit $1 in it.

I dug through my old photos and I took a screenshot of my passphrase but no other information. I'm attaching a photo of what the screen looked like (without the phrase of course). Anyone have any idea which wallet/app/etc... this could be from?!?!?[image]

Comment: is it 12 words? If so it looks like a SEED, you can try to import it in Electrum as Bip39 and see if there is any Bitcoin in it.

Comment: It is 12 words! What is electrum and Bip39? I'm sorry! Outside of that event and couple others I'm a complete novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is 12 words, you can download Electrum that is a Bitcoin wallet and import this SEED. Go to the [website](https://electrum.org/#home) and download and install the wallet on your computer.

Then you will create a new wallet using this SEED, basically, these are the steps to do this:

1 - Go to create new wallet and give any name to this wallet.

2 - Go with the option to standard wallet.

3 - Go with I already have a SEED.

4 - Click on options and check BIP39 SEED and enter with your SEED.

If there is any Bitcoin in this SEED, you will probably see them. You can also try to just paste the SEED without check the option Bip39 in step 4 to see if the SEED will be recognized.

Comment: It worked! Found the transaction with the same date an a cool 8.4 mBTC.

Comment: That is very good!